# Android Monitor shows me a constant memory increment in my application

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, android-camera, surfaceview

I am working in an application for Android and I am using a Surface to read a QR code. Checking the resources with Monitor I see a constant increment of the memory from ~7 MB to ~20 MB, then the memory is released and the behavior starts over. I wonder if it is normal or I am missing something.

### My code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    TextView barCodeInfo;
    SurfaceView cameraSurface;
    Button scan;

    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
    CameraSource cameraSource;

    static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1001;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cameraSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraSurface);
        barCodeInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.barCodeResult);
        scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);

        scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
            } else {
                showCameraPreview();
            }
            }
        });

        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                .build();

        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barCodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (barCodes.size() != 0) {
                    barCodeInfo.post(new Runnable() {    // Use the post method of the TextView
                        public void run() {
                            barCodeInfo.setText(    // Update the TextView
                                    barCodes.valueAt(0).displayValue
                            );
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(200, 200)
                .build();

        cameraSurface.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    private void showCameraPreview() {
        try {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                cameraSource.start(cameraSurface.getHolder());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if(cameraSurface != null){
            cameraSurface = null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            showCameraPreview();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission was denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

### Android Monitor

[image]

The memory is restored only when I close the application.

Comment: It seems completely normal. I used surface one for another task and it had a similar behavior. Also 20MB is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is completely normal. In the course of app being running, resources are allocated in memory and hence memory usage increases (as shown in the android monitor). System keeps on checking free memory to kick off **Garbage Collector** to release any unreferenced memory.

BTW, JVM doesn't run garbage collector until it has to, because the garbage collection **slows things down** quite a bit and thus shouldn't be run very frequently. It runs when there is **need of** memory to be freed. It is always preferred to delay GC as much as possible.

In the image below, sudden release of memory is due to GC event.

[image]

And its a good thing to see that there are not too many GC events because that slows down the app performance.

So if you keep using your app and memory footprints keep on increasing, then GC keeps on freeing them from time to time.